# What is the safest way to get payments in intervals

Tags: square-connect

I am calling the payments api in intervals and specifying the begin_date with the last date/time from the previous call. But it appears that I am periodically missing a payment from what is returned. The payment exists and is returned correctly if I do a full query, but for some reason I don't get it when calling in intervals.
What is the safest way to ensure that I pick up all payments since the last request? Should I always specify an end_date, or perhaps adjust the begin_date back a few seconds?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Mie

Comment: I'll not answer to see if someone else has ideas, but I think my previous answer would work pretty well.

Comment: I can think of two options. Use the created date (>=) greater and equal to. Or use auto increment and another field (backupId) to keep note of all the rows moved. Or use both and look for any discrepancies.